# I want to change dtype from object to int

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda3

```
df['Value'] = [-2,254.00, 3,452.00, 15,698.00, -6,258.00]
```

The datatype is saying object. I would like to convert them into integers, but i am getting an error

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.astype`:

```
In [2329]: df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(int)

In [2329]: df['Value']
Out[2329]: 
0     -2
1    254
2      3
3    452
4     15
5    698
6     -6
7    258
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hie, the numbers are as follows
0    -2,254.00
1   3,452.00
2   15,698.00
3    -6,258.00

Comment: Hi, I have shown the output. `df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(int)` this is my command.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].astype(dtype='int64')
```

Comment: its giving the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,000.00'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`

```
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code is dropping all the negative values

Comment: you are welcome, could you show the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for that. Expected Output would be two extra columns
Index    Value         Value1        Value2
0         -2,254.00     2254.00       0
1        3,452.00           0             3452.00
2       15,698.00          0             15,698.00
3        -6,258.00       6,258.00     0

So the negative numbers go to column Value1 without the - sign, the positive ones to Value2